# How can I get a passport or travel document when I am homeless?

Tags: passports, indian-citizens, paperwork, international-travel

I need to travel to Belgium for marriage to a woman there. However, I am unable to acquire a passport since I am homeless and don't have a residential address needed to apply. I do have a driver's license and PAN card from the time I owned a home. What can I do?

My girlfriend in Belgium is prepared to sponsor everything for me but, without a  passport, I can't travel and settle with her in Belgium.

*Edit to include information OP added as an answer:*

My girlfriend is in Belgium, a Romanian with a resident permit in Belgium. I am from Mumbai, India. She is ready to sponsor everything and is in the process of acquiring information from the Belgian offices there, but I need to get my requisites in order, too. She has a café business, and is hadling everything all alone. She prefers that I travel to her and marry her there. I will be her life as well as business partner.

Comment: What country do you want to apply for a passport from? Homelessness is not an uncommon situation and usually if you are homeless there are ways to get around the usual requirements of proving your residence. But we can't help you until we know which country you're a citizen of.

Comment: @ajd the [tag:indian-citizens] tag implies that the answer to your question is "India."

Comment: You will need both a passport and a visa. Are you aware that getting a visa will be rather difficult without a home?

Comment: @o.m. visitor visa would certainly get denied, family visa maybe not? Not up to date if theres a fiance visa for the Schengen area/Belgium

Comment: @BritishSam, I don't know. It isn't a family situation *yet*, and that part of the problem belongs on Expatriates SE.

Comment: Why doesn’t your girlfriend travel to marry you instead? Probably be an awful lot easier

Comment: @o.m. in the uk you can sponsor your fiance to come, and if you get married within 6 months you stay on the family visa, not sure if elsewhere in europe is the same

Comment: How homeless are you? Sleeping on the street? In a shelter? Changing address every few days? Is there a chance your fiancee would pay for your rent for a couple of months while you got a passport? Doesn't seem like much to ask if she is going to marry you.

Comment: @Traveller It would certainly make it easier to get married, but it would not help with the longer-term goal of living together as a couple in Belgium.  Even after the marriage, the Indian spouse will need an Indian passport to be able to move to Belgium.

Comment: @o.m. from the [requirements for a family reunion visa](http://india.diplomatie.belgium.be/en/travel-to-belgium/visa/india), it appears that the financial circumstances of the Belgian spouse are rather more significant than those of the Indian spouse.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify